# Google Analytics gapi php how can I get event action and unique events

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Ok, so i have this code setup, And I can get my event category and Action and filter everything... but I cannot get it to display unique events. I've add 'number_format($result->uniqueEvents())' after '$result' but that doesn't return anything. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for your help

```
define('ga_email','EMAIL');     // GA Email
define('ga_password','PASSWORD');     // 2-part authorization password
define('profile_id','PROFILE_ID');          // Analytics profile ID
require_once 'gapi/gapi.class.php';
$ga = new gapi(ga_email,ga_password);

$dimensions  = array('eventCategory','eventAction');
$metrics     = array('totalEvents','uniqueEvents', 'eventsPerVisitWithEvent');
$sort_metric = '-totalEvents';

$ga->requestReportData(profile_id,      
$dimensions, 
$metrics, 
$sort_metric, 
$filter='ga:eventAction==company', 
$start_date='2013-07-01', 
$end_date='2013-07-24', 
$start_index=1, 
$max_results=50);

$i = 1;
foreach($ga->getResults() as $result):
echo $result .  number_format($result->uniqueEvents()) . '<br>' ;

endforeach
?>
```

Comment: I think I may have answered my own question... will report back with details

Answer (score 0):

It was a simple thing, I just wasn't applying the right metrics.. anyhow this works for me. I am going to be testing a bunch on this. will give some updates when i have some "cooler" functions.

```
<?php 

define('ga_email','EMAIL');     // GA Email
define('ga_password','PASSWORD');     // 2-part authorization password
define('profile_id','PROFILE_ID');          // Analytics profile ID
require_once 'gapi/gapi.class.php';
$ga = new gapi(ga_email,ga_password);

$dimensions  = array('eventAction');
$metrics     = array('visits','totalEvents','uniqueEvents', 'eventsPerVisitWithEvent');
$sort_metric = '-totalEvents';

$ga->requestReportData(profile_id,      
$dimensions, 
$metrics, 
$sort_metric, 
$filter='ga:eventAction==' . $_GET['company'] , 
$start_date='2013-07-01', 
$end_date='2013-07-24', 
$start_index=1, 
$max_results=50);
?>
<?php
$i = 1;
foreach($ga->getResults() as $result):
echo 'Company: ' . $result . '<br> Number of Calls: ' .number_format($result- >getVisits()) .'<br>' ;

endforeach


?>
```